# NSString question - rangeOfString method

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am having an issue that I can't figure out.

I'm trying to run the rangeOfString method on a string, and I'm not sure how to determine if the string was not found. For example:

```
NSRange range = [@"abc" rangeOfString:@"d" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,3)];
```

Clearly, "d" is not contained in the string "abc." I'd like to be able to do this:

```
if(the range is empty since "d" is not in "abc")
   //do something
```

What is the code for this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From the documentation of **NSString**

```
-[NSString rangeOfString]
```

> Return Value
>
> An NSRange structure giving the
>   location and length in the receiver of
>   the first occurrence of aString.
>   Returns **{NSNotFound, 0}** if aString is
>   not found or is empty (@"").

So it looks like:

```
if ([@"abc" rangeOfString:@"d"].location == NSNotFound){
  //Do something
```

Is the Apple-approved way.

**EDIT:**

I made a really bad typo, fixed it, thanks Kalle.

Comment: You want two equal signs there.

Comment: Does that mean checking the length is not "Apple-approved"? ;-)

Comment: I don't know. And at any rate, just because it's not approved by Apple doesn't make it wrong (see: App Store rejections)

Comment: Checking the length is also correct, but it's certainly less clear

Comment: This method doesn't work in case the string is null. I'd check the length instead.

Answer (score 13):

Check the *length* of the range. If it's non-zero, it was found.

Comment: From the comments in NSString.h : "These methods return length==0 if the target string is not found" . I prefer this approach, as NSNotFound is a #define NSIntegerMax and its value changes depending on the runtime environment (i.e 32 vs 64bit)

Comment: Check for length is better. In case the receiver is nil, the length and location are both returned as 0.