# NSString rangeOfString performing slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have around 10-15 checks where I am checking if a substring exists in the string. An example of one of the checks is as follows :

```
if([request.URL.absoluteString.lowercaseString rangeOfString:@"/group/editgroupmembers?groupid"].location != NSNotFound)
```

I found that it takes few seconds to pass through these checks. To confirm, I debugged the application and found that it takes 1+ second to pass through each of the check.
`rangeOfString` is the [**Apple's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504420/nsstring-question-rangeofstring-method) recommended way for checking existence of substring.
But why does it takes that long ?

Comment: Unless your deployment target is >= 8.x in which case you can simply use `containsString:`, `rangeOfString...` is the way to go, primitively. Alternatively, you could use an `NSPredicate` to find if a string contains another string. Coming to performance issue, the reason may be one(or more) of any: (1) Very long strings in which you are searching. (2) You have dispatched this task to a background/low-priority thread, etc.

Comment: I'd have a look what your code is actually doing. One second to check 10-15 URLs is ridiculous. So there is something you are not telling us, or something your code is doing that you don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Apple String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html) you will also read:

> If you simply want to determine whether a string contains a given pattern, you can use a predicate:

So, in your case you could use predicates to match your search string against your urls, which should give you a better performance:

```
NSString *path = @"/group/editgroupmembers?groupid";
NSPredicate *containsPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", path];

BOOL match = [containsPred evaluateWithObject:request.URL.absoluteString.lowercaseString];
```

You can read more about predicates in the [Apple Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789).

**EDIT**

I did a quick benchmark to check the performance of the various options.

- The first option is to use `rangeOfString:` as the OP did.
- The second option is to use an `NSPredicate`.
- The third option puts all strings into an array and matches the complete array using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`.

The benchmark puts 100k random numerical strings into an array, and checks for the match phrase "123" using the different options. Here is the benchmark code:

```
- (void)benchmarkStringContainment {

    // Setup of array to search through
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfRandomStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        NSString *stringToSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lli", arc4random() % 100000000000];
        [arrayOfRandomStrings addObject:stringToSearch];
    }

    // String we search for
    NSString *matchPhrase = @"123";


    // Method 1: rangeOfSubstring
    NSUInteger matches1 = 0;
    NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        BOOL match = ([[arrayOfRandomStrings[i] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:matchPhrase].location != NSNotFound);
        if (match) matches1++;
    }

    double timePassed1_ms = [date1 timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;
    NSLog(@"Method 1: rangeOfString. Matches: %lu, time taken in ms: %f", (unsigned long)matches1, timePassed1_ms);


    // Setup of NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *containsPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", matchPhrase];

    // Method 2: NSPredicate
    NSUInteger matches2 = 0;
    NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        BOOL match = [containsPred evaluateWithObject:arrayOfRandomStrings[i]];
        if (match) matches2++;
    }

    double timePassed2_ms = [date2 timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;
    NSLog(@"Method 2: NSPredicate. Matches: %lu, time taken in ms: %f", (unsigned long)matches2, timePassed2_ms);


    // Method 3: NSPredicate over NSArray
    NSUInteger matches3 = 0;
    NSDate *date3 = [NSDate date];

    NSArray *filteredArray = [arrayOfRandomStrings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:containsPred];
    matches3 = [filteredArray count];

    double timePassed3_ms = [date3 timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;
    NSLog(@"Method 3: NSPredicate over NSArray. Matches: %lu, time taken in ms: %f", (unsigned long)matches3, timePassed3_ms);

}
```

When testing (debug) on an iPhone 5, a sample result would yield results around 200 ms to 500 ms. Here a typical output:

```
2015-03-13 10:49:27.815 so29003576[1413:494702] Method 1: rangeOfString. Matches: 978, time taken in ms: 443.618000
2015-03-13 10:49:28.090 so29003576[1413:494702] Method 2: NSPredicate. Matches: 978, time taken in ms: 272.534013
2015-03-13 10:49:28.309 so29003576[1413:494702] Method 3: NSPredicate over NSArray. Matches: 978, time taken in ms: 217.999041
```

As next step, I repeated the benchmark multiple times (code not shown), and averaged over the different methods, to get a more representative result:

```
2015-03-13 10:54:01.728 so29003576[1423:495973] Method 1: rangeOfString. Repetitions: 50, average time taken in ms: 449.577812
2015-03-13 10:54:01.731 so29003576[1423:495973] Method 2: NSPredicate. Repetitions: 50, average time taken in ms: 276.818836
2015-03-13 10:54:01.732 so29003576[1423:495973] Method 3: NSPredicate over NSArray. Repetitions: 50, average time taken in ms: 222.459898
```

Although this little benchmark is surely not data-independent, it indicates two results:

1. The fastest of the tested options to find a match phrase in a bunch of strings is option 3, using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`, which is twice as fast as option 1, `rangeOfString:`. Option 2, using `NSPredicate` directly while iterating through the different strings, performs slightly worse than option 3.
2. The benchmark searches the match phrase in 100.000 strings. As indicated by @gnasher729 in one of the comments, the OP must have a different problem in their code, as even the slowest method should be orders of magnitude faster on 10 to 15 URLs.

Comment: How is that going to be faster than the original code?

Comment: @gnasher729: You are right, the OP surely has a different problem. However, your comment motivated me to test the performance of the different methods with a little benchmark anyway. See my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are checking for substring in a URL then you could probably try `NSURLComponents`.

```
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:request.URL.absoluteString];
if ([urlComponents.path rangeOfString:@"/group/editgroupmembers"].location != NSNotFound) {
  for (NSURLQueryItem *item in urlComponents.queryItems) {
    if ([item.name isEqualToString:@"groupid"]) {
      //your code goes here...
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

Try this and let me know if this improved the performance. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this makes a difference to what the user already has as the answer still uses `rangeOfString:` and doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: Well in the question the user searches the entire url string but in the above approach the user will be only searching the path. This would reduce the loops and hence improve the performance. This may not be the optimum approach but it could improve the performance by some amount.